# What's difference between MathKernel.exe and WolframKernel.exe?

Tags: kernel, installation, version-10.1

Recently I installed *Mathematica 10.1* and noticed two different files (they have the same length, but different hashes) in the installation folder: `MathKernel.exe` and `WolframKernel.exe`. It appears that the latter one is actually running when I start a new kernel session. IIRC, previous versions of *Mathematica* had only `MathKernel.exe`.

What's the difference between these two files, and what's the purpose of having both of them?